# What's the meaning of 'the eventual repair of ecosystems' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Vertical farms would need to be efficient, cheap to construct and safe to operate. If successfully implemented, proponents claim, vertical farms offer the promise of urban renewal, sustainable production of a safe and varied food supply (through year-round production of all crops), and **the eventual repair of ecosystems** that have been sacrificed for horizontal farming.

Source: [Mini-ielts.com: Crop-growing skyscrapers](http://mini-ielts.com/386/view-solution/reading/crop-growing-skyscrapers)

Comment: Why haven't you looked up the words?

Answer (score 0):

The ***repair of ecosystems*** means the ecosystems recovering to the state they were in before they were damaged. The fact it's *repair* rather than *recovery* suggests that it is a result of deliberate action.

The fact it's ***eventual*** means that it will take a long time before it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Some European languages have cognate words with a slightly different meaning, like the French  adjective *éventuel* and adverb *éventuellement*. This is something that might happen in the future, something potential or possible or optional.

But in English, "eventual" usually refers to something that will definitely happen in the long run. "When" and "how" are uncertain, but not "if". Probably there will be a considerable delay.

So this new vertical farm technology, if it works, will at some point in the future allow farmland to be abandoned and to revert back to its natural state of forests or meadows.